# How to use React Code Splitting and Firebase Hosting without ChunkLoadError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app, firebase-hosting

I need to use [React Codes Splitting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/code-splitting/) with a Create React App, hosted on Firebase Hosting.

However, I have a problem, because **Firebase Hosting only hosts the latest version** of any app. This means that if you deploy a *new* app version (N+1), and a user has the existing version open (N), and that user crosses a code splitting boundary, they will request a old chunk (N), which is no longer hosted in Firebase Hosting, because the current version has changed (N+1).

So, how does one avoid Code Splitting `ChunkLoadError`s in Firebase Hosting? Is there a way to tell Firebase Hosting to retain all prior versions you've deployed, and only add the new files from the latest release (e.g. `index.html` and the JS/CSS chunks?).

Comment: This is a problem I've been struggling ever since I started hosting my app on Firebase hosting as well. AFAIK there is no out of the box solution for this issue, but there are two things you could do:
1) handle the error in JS and reload the page when a user hits a `ChunkLoadError`
2) use custom scripting like this (https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412) to deploy new files to Firebase hosting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this using the following process:

1. Push files for each new release to a bucket, like `gs://my-buck/app/releases/<git-sha>/`
2. Make a release folder locally, like `firebase_deploy/`
3. Identify the last `N` release tags in the git history
4. For each old release, `gsutil -m -q rsync -rc gs://my-buck/app/releases/<git-sha>/ firebase_deploy/` to copy **old** files down
5. Copy the **new** release files `rsync -rvc build/ firebase_deploy/`
6. Deploy the app to Firebase from `firebase_deploy/`, with your **new** and **old** chunks, giving preference to the new chunks where any conflict might occur.

This process eliminated the ChunkLoadErrors for me.

Note: Use a bounded `N` prior releases, so you don't run up your Firebase Hosting storage bill. If you don't have many artifacts, you could possibly retain all previous releases, if you wanted.