# How to prevent deletion of old hashed build files and merge them instead

Tags: sveltekit

When building an `adapter-static` project inside `build/_app/immutable` there are some folders containing `.css` and `.js` files all with a hash like `_page-65dc5ef0.css`

Is there a way to prevent the deletion of these files and add the newly built ones instead?

I found the [`emptyOutDir`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-emptyoutdir) flag, but setting it `vite.config` or `svelte.config.js` doesn't seem to have an effect.

There are two reasons I would like to keep the old files

- older session recordings won't be displayed correctly if the corresponding .css file isn't available anymore
- additional files are fetched when the user navigates on the site. As I understand these files might be deleted because of the new build and lead to errors. I assume this might be solved by watching the version number and do a full-page navigation after a change, but since the initial load of the page is quite big, this wouldn't go unnoticed for the user and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Why do you need the old files?

Comment: @H.B. just added some more info

Comment: SvelteKit will force a hard reload automatically when it detects that files of the older version are gone. You can also add additional logic in the UI using the [`updated`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-updated) store. If anything, I would try to merge older version files on deployment, not on build (where if you have a clean checkout, there will be no older files anyway).

Comment: @H.B. Interesting that there should be a mechanism that forces a hard reload. I did encounter `Failed to fetch dynamically imported module` errors, where the automatic reload doesn't seem to have worked then. As mentioned I would prefer to 'suppress' it anyway and keep the old version working instead. The user is informed about the update thanks to the `updated` store and can refresh when/if he likes. What's a clean checkout?

Comment: As in version control. Getting the source files, which generally should *not* include the build or stuff like `node_modules`.

Comment: @H.B. I see, makes sense. So I'll look for a solution to merge the files with firebase hosting like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286540/how-to-use-react-code-splitting-and-firebase-hosting-without-chunkloaderror